# BLE113 data reading in LabView - lower sampling frequency

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, labview, sample-rate

my goal is to obtain the data from BLE113 and processed them in Labview. I managed it using the BLE toolkit and it works. However, the sampling frequency is lower than it should be (1000 S/s). The number of samples per second is around 940 instead of the proper value. I would like to ask you for some advice about how to solve this problem.

Thank you,
Daniel

Comment: Would you share any references you used (eg, where does SiLabs claim 1000 S/s, and is that for the ADC or ??) and how you're programming and interfacing with the chip?

Comment: I am sorry for the small mistake, it should be 100 S/s, not 1000 S/s. However, it does not change the problem. I set the sample rate of the BLE in this command `call hardware_set_soft_timer(32768/100,0,0)`. I acquire an analog signal using `hardware_adc_read`. The BLE is programmed by CC debugger and BLE SW Update Tool. The interface between BLE113 and LabView is managed by LabView BLE Toolkit and USB dongle (COM port).